# How does the memory management work for creating view controllers on a navigation controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app that uses a navigation controller.  The views display results from picking a ranom card from a deck.  The logic of what card was picked and what options to use is determined in the OnCreate of each view.

After I go through the views then I go back to the root view.  Now when I go back through the vues, the same information is being shown and oncreate is not being called.  It seems like when I go back to the root views, the vues that get popped off memory are not being freed, so it is using the same object.  Is this how its suppose to work, or am I doing something wrong so popToRootViewController is not releasing the meory the views where using?

I'm using the following code to go to the next view

```
if (mGet == nil) {
    mGet = [[cGet  alloc] initWithNibName:@"cGet" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `-viewDidLoad` to perform one-time setup of your view controller at the point that all view objects are instantiated. Just before a viewController presents its view, `-viewWillAppear:` is executed. Just before a viewController's view goes away, `-viewWillDisappear:` is executed. So when you need to respond to a viewController displaying its view, or going offscreen, override `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewWillDisappear:` in your view controller.

Check the [Apple documentation for UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for these details.